Letter after year in citations need to be reset after \newrefsection
so the title is what I'd like to do.
I have half a document with a first set of citations and in the second half I have to cite some of the same sources again, but if they have the lettering from the first refsection it is wrong.
For instance, in the first section there is:
\nocite{smith1999}\nocite{smith1999a}

The printbibliography would correctly give me Smith 1999a and Smith 1999b.
But if I cite only {smith1999b} after \newrefsection Smith 1999b looks weird because Smith 1999a belongs to what came before \newrefsection.
I thought \newrefsection and running bibtex on the two separate files that are produced already would solve this issue, but I must be mistaken.
I'm using multiple bibliography headings and keywords to sort out what appears in the bibliography where. That is working.

I found the answer. Getting rid of extradate as suggested here also works for this issue.
Suppress year label letter in biblatex author-year styles on a per-bibliography or per-keyword basis
\defbibenvironment{nodis}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\clearfield{extradate}\item}

